# Pandas get end of trading time per day from datetime index and add it back as new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a set of minute stock trading data with a DateTime Index, and OHLC columns.

```
|                      |Open     |High     |Low      |Close   |
| DateTime             |         |         |         |        |
| 2019-01-02 09:30:00  |2476.96  |2476.96  |2470.98  |2470.40 |
| 2019-01-02 09:31:00  |2470.80  |2474.09  |2473.70  |2470.80 |
| 2019-01-02 09:32:00  |2473.56  |2473.56  |2471.44  |2471.26 |
| 2019-01-02 09:33:00  |2471.30  |2472.88  |2471.67  |2469.64 |
| 2019-01-02 09:34:00  |2471.88  |2472.49  |2471.04  |2470.11 |
| ...                  |    ...  |    ...  |    ...  |    ... |
| 2019-12-31 15:55:00  |3228.82  |3230.04  |3228.62  |3230.04 |
| 2019-12-31 15:56:00  |3230.06  |3230.08  |3228.42  |3228.42 |
| 2019-12-31 15:57:00  |3228.23  |3228.47  |3227.39  |3227.62 |
| 2019-12-31 15:58:00  |3227.70  |3228.14  |3227.21  |3227.58 |
| 2019-12-31 15:59:00  |3227.75  |3231.72  |3227.75  |3230.56 |
```

I'd like to find the last trading time per day and have that time added to the original data frame.
Most trading days end at 15:99  but some end at  12:59.

```
|                      |Open     |High     |Low      |Close    |EOD   |
| DateTime             |         |         |         |         |      |
| 2019-01-02 09:30:00  |2476.96  |2476.96  |2470.98  |2470.40  |15:59 |
| 2019-01-02 09:31:00  |2470.80  |2474.09  |2473.70  |2470.80  |15:59 |
| 2019-01-02 09:32:00  |2473.56  |2473.56  |2471.44  |2471.26  |15:59 |
| 2019-01-02 09:33:00  |2471.30  |2472.88  |2471.67  |2469.64  |15:59 |
| 2019-01-02 09:34:00  |2471.88  |2472.49  |2471.04  |2470.11  |12:59 |
| ...                  |    ...  |    ...  |    ...  |    ...  |      |
| 2019-12-31 15:55:00  |3228.82  |3230.04  |3228.62  |3230.04  |15:59 |
| 2019-12-31 15:56:00  |3230.06  |3230.08  |3228.42  |3228.42  |15:59 |
| 2019-12-31 15:57:00  |3228.23  |3228.47  |3227.39  |3227.62  |15:59 |
| 2019-12-31 15:58:00  |3227.70  |3228.14  |3227.21  |3227.58  |15:59 |
| 2019-12-31 15:59:00  |3227.75  |3231.72  |3227.75  |3230.56  |15:59 |
```

This grouped data frame gives me the correct end times per day.

```py
SPX1m["DT"] = SPX1m.index
a = SPX1m.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))["DT"].max().dropna()
print(a)
```

The above gives me this series

```
| DateTime     |                    |
| 2019-01-02   |2019-01-02 15:59:00 |
| 2019-01-03   |2019-01-03 15:59:00 |
| 2019-01-04   |2019-01-04 15:59:00 |
| 2019-01-07   |2019-01-07 15:59:00 |
| 2019-01-08   |2019-01-08 15:59:00 |
|              |                    |
| 2019-12-24   |2019-12-24 12:59:00 |
| 2019-12-26   |2019-12-26 15:59:00 |
| 2019-12-27   |2019-12-27 15:59:00 |
| 2019-12-30   |2019-12-30 15:59:00 |
| 2019-12-31   |2019-12-31 15:59:00 |
```

`Name: DT, Length: 252, dtype: datetime64[ns]`

But now I struggle to expand that result back to the original data frame as a new column
I tried this, but it does not work as expected.

```py
b = pd.concat([SPX1m, a], axis=1)
print(b)
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not figure out how to do the tables correctly in this post.
Will try to fix them when I can do another change.
Is there a possibility to preview the post, ... before posting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.merge() to combine your original data frame with the result of the groupby operation, using the date as the common key.

Here is the code you can use:

```
# create a new data frame from the groupby result
eod = SPX1m.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))["DT"].max().dropna().reset_index()

# rename the "DT" column to "EOD"
eod = eod.rename(columns={"DT": "EOD"})

# merge the original data frame with the new data frame on the date column
merged = pd.merge(SPX1m, eod, left_on=SPX1m.index.date, right_on="DateTime", how="left")

# drop the "DateTime" column and set "EOD" as the index
merged = merged.drop("DateTime", axis=1).set_index("EOD")
```

What this code does is:

1. Create a new data frame eod from the groupby result, with the date and the last trading time for each day.
2. Rename the "DT" column to "EOD".
3. Merge the original data frame SPX1m with the eod data frame, using the date as the common key. The resulting data frame merged has a new "EOD" column that contains the last trading time for each row.
4. Drop the "DateTime" column, which is no longer needed, and set "EOD" as the index.

This should give you the desired output

Comment: Thanks Luke, although it did not work out of the box, it pointed me in the right direction.  This is now significantly faster than looping through the index I did before.

Answer (score 0):

Luke's answer pointed me in the right direction.
But tweaks were needed.

1. Import the data (didn't have that in my initial post)

```py
SPX1m = pd.read_csv("./stockData/SPX.csv", index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True)
# print(SPX1m)
```

2. Adding additional columns to prepare for the join

```py
# create a new data frame from the groupby result
SPX1m['Time'] = SPX1m.index.time
SPX1m['Date'] = SPX1m.index.date
SPX1m['DT'] = SPX1m.index
    
# print(SPX1m)
```

3. Create EOD data frame through group by on a daily aggregation carrying the max of Date and Time

```py
eod = SPX1m.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).agg({"Date": "max", "Time": "max"}).dropna()
# print(eod)
```

4. Merge EOD data frame with initial dataframe

```py
# merge the original data frame with the new data frame on the date column
merged = pd.merge(left=SPX1m, right=eod, how='left', on='Date')
```

5. Cleanup of index and column names

```py
merged.rename(columns={"DT": "DateTime"}, inplace=True)
merged.rename(columns={"Time_y": "EOD"}, inplace=True)
merged.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)
merged
```

Here the resulting data frame

```
                        Open        High        Low         Close       Time_x      Date        EOD
DateTime                            
2019-01-02 09:30:00     2476.96     2476.96     2470.98     2470.40     09:30:00    2019-01-02  15:59:00
2019-01-02 09:31:00     2470.80     2474.09     2473.70     2470.80     09:31:00    2019-01-02  15:59:00
2019-01-02 09:32:00     2473.56     2473.56     2471.44     2471.26     09:32:00    2019-01-02  15:59:00
2019-01-02 09:33:00     2471.30     2472.88     2471.67     2469.64     09:33:00    2019-01-02  15:59:00
2019-01-02 09:34:00     2471.88     2472.49     2471.04     2470.11     09:34:00    2019-01-02  15:59:00
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2019-12-31 15:55:00     3228.82     3230.04     3228.62     3230.04     15:55:00    2019-12-31  15:59:00
2019-12-31 15:56:00     3230.06     3230.08     3228.42     3228.42     15:56:00    2019-12-31  15:59:00
2019-12-31 15:57:00     3228.23     3228.47     3227.39     3227.62     15:57:00    2019-12-31  15:59:00
2019-12-31 15:58:00     3227.70     3228.14     3227.21     3227.58     15:58:00    2019-12-31  15:59:00
2019-12-31 15:59:00     3227.75     3231.72     3227.75     3230.56     15:59:00    2019-12-31  15:59:00

97740 rows × 7 columns
```